# Features Vectors to build classifier to detect subjectivity

Tags: text-mining, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to build a classifier to detect subjectivity. I have text files tagged with subjective and objective . I am little lost with the concept of features creation from this data. I have found the lexicon of the subjective and objective tag. One thing that I can do is to create a feature of having words present in respective dictionary. Maybe the count of words present in subjective and objective dictionary. After that I intend to use naive bayes or SVM to develop the model

My problem is as follow

- Is my approach correct ?
- Can I create more features ? If possible suggest some or point me to some paper or link
- Can I do some test like chi -sq etc to identify effective words from the dictionary ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use opinion mining tools. Neutral sentences will probably be non-subjective.

BTW, can you please share the dataset? It might be very helpful for my research.

Thanks a lot!